# Can a Custom Field be added to a Contribution Page or Financial Type?

Tags: custom-fields, contributions, financial-types

I have created a Set of Custom Fields called "Tracking" to be used with -any- Contributions.  The set includes Custom Fields called "Category" and "Job".

I would like to assign specific Category and Job codes to all payments made via a specific Contribution Page.  Can a Contribution Page be edited to add Custom Fields?

Alternatively, can a Financial Type be edited to add Custom Fields?

Answer (score 4):

1. Under Administer > Custom Data and Screens, Create your Custom Fields
2. Under Administer > Profiles, Create a Profile that has your Custom Fields in it.
3. Under Conrtibutions > Manage Contribution Pages, select the Page you want it to appear on. Under the Include Profiles tab, add that Profile. You can add it at the top or bottom of the Contribution Page.

Answer (score 2):

This extension will let you create custom fields on Financial Types: https://github.com/pradpnayak/org.civicrm.financialtypecustomfield